# Настройка rewrite_mod в apache2

Tags: .htaccess, apache, apache2, mod-rewrite

Есть сайт, который состоит из двух папок:

- `public` (публичный)
- `app` (ядро / компоненты / конфиги)

В папке `public` находится `index.php` (который подключает роутер) + `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?uri=$1 [QSA,L]
```

В `app` - `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
```

Нужно сделать, чтобы все запросы переадресовывались на `public`.

Как правильнее и безопаснее настроить сайт, и есть ли разница настраивать в конфигах сайта или через файлики `.htaccess`?

Comment: Вам нужно сделать `public` корневой директорией, тогда все запросы будут обрабатываться через `.htaccess` в ней, а папка `app` не будет видна из вне, что повысит безопасность.